# Ajax error: "Unknown web method. Parameter name: methodName"

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I'm experiencing troubles when I make an ajax call that goes like this:

```
function ajaxCall() {
   var a = {};
   var aJSON = JSON.stringify(a);

   $.ajax({
     async: false,
     url: 'PersonaFisica.aspx/metodo',
     cache: false,
     dataType: 'json',
     type: 'POST',
     data: aJSON,
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
         alert('Success!');
     }
     });
}
```

The C# code goes like this:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string metodo()
{
     return string.Empty;
}
```

I found some solutions over the net, but none of them works.

What I tried:

- Adding/Removing 'static' from the method.
- Changing method name
- Setting full path of the C# aspx file to 'url' property on the ajax call.
- Adding parameters to the method and the ajax call
- Removing the [ScriptMethod] line

I don't know what to do, so I'll appreciate any help!

Cheers.

Comment: I'm not a .Net WebMethod guru, but I can't help but notice that you're saying to the web method that it's **response** should be JSON, but you're **sending** JSON *to* it.

Comment: I have tried with your code but not able to replicate your issue. Could you please create new page/web application and check your code in it. I have used VS2012 and .net framework 4.5.

Comment: Well, I used this type of ajax call like hundreds of times and never gave me trouble. I suspect that is something out of this code what is causing problem, but I can't think of anything. If any of you knows what could be, that'll be really helpful.

Comment: what if you remove the parameters for the ajax call? Also try viewing through developer tools to see what is being sent / received

Comment: You dont have to send data. data: aJSON

Comment: Already tried, nothing :(

Comment: debug and see the response